# Importing multiple files into MySQL table

Tags: php, mysql, load-data-infile

I am trying to import a bunch of text files(3098) into a MySQL table. There is no problem importing a single file by `LOAD DATA LOCAL INFIE`. All my files are in one folder. I reckon i need to use foreach but not sure how to do it.Is that possible without php. Anything would be helpful.

Comment: @spartan and without php?

Comment: I am wondering if there is a  way to do that with a MySQL loop, cause i'm having a problem conecting my database to php. @Strawberry

Answer (score 1):

run the following shell script

```
for f in /path/to/files/folder/*.txt
do
    mysql -e "LOAD DATA INFILE '"$f"' INTO TABLE [tablename] FIELDS TERMINATED BY ',' LINES TERMINATED BY '\n' IGNORE 1 LINES" -u [username] --password= [password] [databasename]
echo "Done: '"$f"' at $(date)"
done
```

Comment: I ran this script. It took quite a while and  it displayed  `Done` for the last file. But when i checked the table the files were still missing.

Comment: Sorry for beeing such a noob but I have tried the code by itself so the only place I may be wrong is `-u [username] --password= [password] [databasename]`. If my pass is "pass" and database is "work" it shall be `-u root --password=pass work`,or?

Comment: If you have any ideas @coding-dude.com

Comment: yes, that's how it should be. Did it give any errors? Also, please make sure that the path to the folder where you have the files is correct. The command takes all the files with the extension .txt and with the fields delimited with a comma (,)

Comment: The path to the files is correct, cause it is looping through them to show me the `Done` message. But the problem is that theese files aren't going into the corresponding table in my database. @coding-dude.com

Comment: And also. no it didn't give any errors.